# PHP - make file accessible for script but not for users

Tags: php, file-upload, directory, hidden

I want users to be able to upload files, but I don't want them to be able to view the contents of the folder which the files are uploaded to. A PHP script should be able to browse and read the files in the hidden (for the users) folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upload to a folder that's not in `public_html` - they can then only be accessed via FTP or the server itself, not by HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

Theres multiple ways of accomplishing this.

option1 : like kolink says, place the files outside of your webroot (public_html)

option2 : use a .htaccess where you deny access to the dir, if you dont want the files to be listed you can use the following in your .htaccess

> Options -Indexes

You might also wanna look at the permissions for the files using chmod.

Comment: If I deny access to the dir, won't it deny scripts trying to access it too?

Comment: @quano, no. This will just disable the access to the default index.php file that shows the directory's content and return a 403 - Forbidden message (that you can customize) instead. So you won't access a/dir, but a/dir/file.png.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally secure, but a simple solution would be to place an index.php file in the folder you don't want accessed, that redirects the user back to the homepage. This will mainly prevent easy browsing of unindexed folders.

```
<?php
    header('Location: ../../index.html');
?>
```